# Active Record - User.new throws no error if invalid data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have a User model in rails with a date field called `birth_date` and an integer field called `some_number`. My problem is that if I do `User.new(birth_date: "foo", some_number: "bar")`, I will get no error. In fact I will get `#<User id: nil, birth_date: nil, some_number: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

I would like to have an error telling me that this field was not valid, so that the client can be warned. But since I do not necessarily need a birth_date then I cannot use a validation of birth_date with presence true. So the User end up being saved into the database with a birth_date equal to nil and no error.

The goal here is that if birth_date was sent in the params, then we will either save into the database with birth_date equal to nil BUT get an error message OR we don't save into the database at all. If birth_date was not sent in the params we don't throw an error.

I thought about a workaround that would look at the fields that were present in the params, look at what is indeed recorded into the database and compare the two. But I thought a nicer way probably exist.

For you to test, here is some code:

- User model

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  end
- User migration

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

```
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.date :birth_date
      t.integer :some_number

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

- User Controller

  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def create
      user = User.new(birth_date: "foo", some_number: "bar")
      raise user.inspect
    end
  end

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: should the `has_key` method not fit your needs? You can then check with `if params.has_key(:birth_date) then`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create a custom validation (see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations)) that adds the desired message to the error array on the user instance. The guide walks through the salient bits.